# Ractive expressions not working after a reset()

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

My team is currently using Ractive to show a series of alerts. Each alert:

- Renders a view with Ractive
- Start Twitters `widgets.js` which does some DOM manipulation (to embed Tweets)
- Changes the data in that view later (when the user selects a different alert)

Since Twitter's DOM changes interfere with Ractive's virtual DOM, we currently use [`ractive.reset()`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-reset) to reset the DOM after Twitter's `widgets.js` finishes - the `reset()` prevents a whole bunch of DOM problems like `cannot appendChild of null` which would occur because Twitter has manipulated the DOM behind Ractive's back.

However after we run `ractive.reset()` expressions no longer seem to work.

Is this the right way to handle other libraries that might manipulate the DOM? How can I make expressions continue to work after the `reset()` ?

Here's a quick demo - note the expression works before the `reset()` but not afterwards:

```
    <body>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <div class="bound"></div>
        <script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>

        <script>
            var binding = new Ractive({
                el: document.querySelector('.bound'),
                data: {
                    name: 'mike',
                    swaggify: function(string) {return 'SWAG'+string}
                },
                template: '<p>Hello, {{ swaggify(name) }}!</p>'
            })

            binding.reset().then(function(){
                binding.data.name = 'steve'
            })
        </script>
    </body>
```

And the [obligatory JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/va6jU/59/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `ractive.reset()`, it replaces the `data` object - in this case, that includes the `swaggify` function. If you put it back, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/49JAK/

(Note that I've put the update code immediately after the call to `binding.reset()` - the changes happen synchronously, the `.then()` just allows you to schedule a function for when any transitions have completed. It's Promises/A+ compliant so the code inside `.then()` will always be asynchronous - in some situations that can cause flicker, so sync > async where possible.)

That's probably not what you want though - you want to be able to treat the data and the formatters differently. A good approach is to put the formatters on the prototypal `data` object that all others inherit from:

```
var helpers = Ractive.defaults.data; // Ractive.defaults === Ractive.prototype
helpers.swaggify = function(string) {return 'SWAG'+string};

var binding = new Ractive({
  el: document.querySelector('.bound'),
  data: {
    name: 'mike',
    swaggify: function(string) {return 'SWAG'+string}
  },
  template: '<p>Hello, {{ swaggify(name) }}!</p>'
})
```

Demo of this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/chYD6/.